# Linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Any linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is of the form $X⟼Tr(AX)$ for some $A∈M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$.
Can this statement be proved with the help of the Riesz representation theorem
and also by any other method?

Comment: You don't need Riesz. It is obvious - see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/linear-functional-on-matrix-space-nonnegative-on-positive-semidefinite-matrices), point 1.)

Answer (score 2):

The bilinear form $\varphi : \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$\varphi(A,B)=\mathrm{Tr}(AB)$$

is non-degenerated, hence it induces a canonical isomorphism $ \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \left( \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\right)^*$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Riesz theorem, indeed
$$\langle A, B\rangle=\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B)$$

is an inner product on $M_n(\mathbb C)$, the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product?wprov=sfti1). So any linear form $h(X)$ on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ can be written as

$$h(X)=\mathrm{Tr}(A^*X).$$

Riesz representation theorem is however as mentioned in a comment an over killer as the result is quite obvious if you just write what $\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B)$ is for any matrix $A$.